# Plot from list of tuples in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Given a list of tuples of the form:

```
[((a,b),4),((c,d),8...]
```

where a,b are co-occurrences and we need to plot a barplot against the the number of times they occur (integer). (a,b) ->Label & 4-> Frequency (To be plotted).

Can it be done with matplotlib bar?

Comment: What are the types of a, b, etc?

Comment: @DYZ Both are of String type

Comment: Convert the tuples into strings, then (say, by concatenating the first and the last items), and use them as bar labels.

Comment: Show us the code of what you have tried, so we can help you ...

Answer (score 2):

The following shows how to plot the given list as bar plot in matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [((1,0),4),((0,1),8), ((2,1),2),((3,1),5),((4,2),7),((3,0),3)] 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(range(len(l)), [t[1] for t in l]  , align="center")
ax.set_xticks(range(len(l)))
ax.set_xticklabels([t[0] for t in l])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution using Pandas. Build a dataframe with the list of tuples is quick and easy and adding a bar plot can also be done in pandas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

l = [((1,0),4),((0,1),8), ((2,1),2),((3,1),5),((4,2),7),((3,0),3)] 

pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['label','value']).set_index('label').plot(kind='bar');
```

[image]